# HTML5 input numeric between numbers

Tags: html, input, numeric

How do I check with HTML5 if input is between 1-100?

```
<input type="numeric" name="count" pattern="[1-9]" />
```

Answer (score 11):

Using `min` and `max`.

```
<input type="number" name="count" min="1" max="100">
```

Note the `type` is `number`.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score.